# An undeliverable email that I didn't know I was sending

Tags: gmail, contacts-group

When I forward an email to my contacts group, I get an undeliverable reply for an address that I didn't know I was forwarding it to. It is an address that is not known to me and not visible in the address bar. How can I find out where it is coming from and how to stop it?

Comment: Based on the keywords, I assume this is about Gmail. Please be more specific in the future.

Comment: I wonder if one of your addressees has set up a forward.  I don't know if this might give you an undeliverable response.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Analyze the email headers

## Explanation

From [1]

> Email headers determine where a message is sent, and records the
> specific path the message follows as it passes through each mail
> server.

Go to [1] to learn more about the how to read email message headers.

Go to [2] for instructions on finding headers for a message.

## Reference

- [1] [Reading full email headers - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en)
- [2] [Message Headers - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en)